# How do I get started with multi-agent reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, deep-rl, gym, multi-agent-rl

Is there any *tutorial* that walks through a multi-agent reinforcement learning implementation (in Python) using libraries such as [OpenAI's Gym](https://gym.openai.com/) (for the environment), [TF-agents](https://www.tensorflow.org/agents), and [stable-baselines-3](https://github.com/DLR-RM/stable-baselines3)?

I searched a lot, but I was not able to find any tutorial, mostly because Gym environments and most RL libraries are not for multi-agent RL.

Comment: That question was focusing more on specific setting of multi agent learning explained in three bullet points. This question focuses more on the specific libraries, namely three: OpenAI gym, tf-agents and stable-baseline-3. The two are definitely not the same. Unfortunately, there is no answer on both questions.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://ai.stackexchange.com/q/26806/1794, https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/90626/8560.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

After [checking the Internet](https://www.google.com/search?ei=2QtPYNbSItCIlwS3jIR4&q=github%20multi%20agent%20reinforcement%20learning&oq=github%20multi%20agent%20reinforcement%20learning), you will probably find several resources such as

- https://github.com/mohammadasghari/dqn-multi-agent-rl
- https://rlss.inria.fr/files/2019/07/RLSS_Multiagent.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.00583
  and others.

Try to understand the principles first (see above). After some reasonable amount of coding you can adapt OpenAI gym.
Good luck!

**Update 17 March 2022**:

You may want to check this popular repository as well https://github.com/Farama-Foundation/PettingZoo

**Update 06 August 2023**:

The best multi-agent tutorial I have seen so far comes from RLlib documentation. See [RLlib for muti-agent RL](https://applied-rl-course.netlify.app/en/module2).

Answer (score 0):

Multi-Agent Deep Reinforcement Learning in 13 Lines of Code Using **PettingZoo**

A tutorial on multi-agent deep reinforcement learning for beginners.

This tutorial provides a simple introduction to using multi-agent reinforcement learning, assuming a little experience in machine learning and knowledge of Python.

https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-agent-deep-reinforcement-learning-in-15-lines-of-code-using-pettingzoo-e0b963c0820b

Answer (score 0):

[Hugging Face RL Tutorial](https://huggingface.co/learn/deep-rl-course/unit7/introduction) has a practical tutorial on Multi-agent reinforcement learning.

For those who want to dive deeper, it has [a reading list](https://huggingface.co/learn/deep-rl-course/unit7/additional-readings) at the end that covers its theory and more advance techniques.